# S3 is not detecting the bucket policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an Amazon S3 bucket and I want to provide access to all my corporate users, which means anybody can access the S3 bucket and download objects.

I have written a Bucket Policy for IP restriction:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyIPRestrict",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "10.0.8.10"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I add ACL permission as everyone "read" then only I am able to access the object. But the bucket policy is not applying. Anybody can access from outside the network also. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please Edit your Question and show us your Bucket Policy (feel free to change the IP address). Also, please provide details about *how* your users are accessing the bucket -- is it via an anonymous URL in a web browser, via the AWS Management Console, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), etc? The more information you can provide, the better the chance of receiving a useful answer.

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyIPRestrict",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::insight.application.log-464413482301-us-east-1/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "10.0.8.10",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: This the policy i m using.. i want to make sure.. everyone can access but inside corporate network.. tats y i used ip restriction

Comment: It looks like you have a Direct Connect/VPN connection to AWS, which is why you are using a Private IP address. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your bucket policy is granting permission for a source IP address of `10.0.8.10`. This is a **private IP address**.

However, Amazon S3 is a public service sitting on the Internet. When accessing Amazon S3, requests go across the Internet (or at least to the AWS edge of the Internet) and your request will appear to be coming from a **Public IP address**. Therefore, the policy is not permitting access, since your address does not match the one in the policy.

You should change the policy to use the **Public IP address** that is used when your corporate traffic access the Internet. You could discover this address via `http://checkip.amazonaws.com`.

Also, if you are granting access via a Bucket Policy, you should *not* grant access via the ACLs.